# How to prevent duplicate records in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

The person I would have selected will then appears as twice in my friends database. How do I prevent a duplicate entry going in here? I have tried using exists sql command but no luck

friends model:

```
   function addFriend($username, $friendname)
 {
$record = array('username'=> $username,
                 'friend' => $friendname);

$this->db->insert('friends', $record);


 }


 function getFollowing($username)
{
$following = array();
$this->db->select('*')->from('friends')->where('username', $username);
$followingSet = $this->db->get();
foreach ($followingSet->result() as $row)
{
    if(isset($username)){

        $following[] = $row->friend;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;


    }

}

return $following;
}
```

view:

```
 <?php foreach($friends['following'] as $name):?>
        <li>  <?=anchor("profile/view/$name", $name)?>, (<?=anchor("home/drop/$name", 'drop')?>)</li>
      <?php endforeach?>=
```

The thing I want to do is stop duplicate entries going in my database - how would I use the exists keyword in my sql statement?

Comment: Use CI's validation rule `is_unique`

Comment: "stop duplicate entries going in my database"... what do you mean... i see no insert queries in you question or any thing that does the entries,,,

Comment: what you are trying to do?to prevent  duplicate entries in database or prevent  selecting repeated entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert you can call your `getFollowing` method and go like this:

```
function add_follower($username, $friend_username)
{
    $current_followers = $this->getFollowing($username);

    if(!in_array($friend_username, $current_followers)
    {
        // Add to followers
    }
 }
```

For this you need to change your `getFollowing` to this:

```
function getFollowing($username)
{
    $following = array();

    $this->db->select('*')->from('friends')->where('username', $username);

    $followingSet = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($followingSet->result() as $row)
    {
        $following[] = $row->friend;
    }
    return $following;
}
```

This will not work 100% right probably, because I have no idea how your database / models are configured. But it should give you a general idea on how to do this

Comment: This pulls all the records from the table, just to check if one username is in the resulting array. I think it would be more efficient to specifically query for one username's existence (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

Just perform a check to see if the username/friendname exists before inserting:

```
$q =  $this->db->select('username')
      ->from('friends')
      ->where(array('username' => $username, 'friend' => $friendname))->get();
if($q->num_rows() == 0){
    //insert goes here
}
```

Comment: I really wanted to use this as it seemed simple to understand but then I got this error regarding my sql syntax: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id #32, Resource id #40, 0, 0, NULL)' at line 1

INSERT INTO `friends` (`conn_id`, `result_id`, `current_row`, `num_rows`, `row_data`) VALUES (Resource id #32, Resource id #40, 0, 0, NULL)

Comment: A literally simple to understand answer. Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

I think your didn't set up your tables for better performance.

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
friendId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (userId)
    REFERENCES users(userId)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (friendId)
    REFERENCES users(userId)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE friends ADD UNIQUE INDEX (userId, friendId);
```

This clear and simple solution to store friends by id and will prevent duplicating. InnoDB engine maintains your data integrity, and when you delete somebody from users table - all rows in friends table with wriends of this users will be deleted automatically.

Comment: The other answers that suggest checking before inserting are going to fail one day unless this is a trivial single user database. The correct way to prevent duplicates is to apply constraints at the database level and not in the application logic. Pavel K has listed the only correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a check in database before inserting the new record that is there any entry already in database. Below is the code...

```
function addFriend($username, $friendname)
{
    $user_name = $this->getFollowing($username);

    if( empty($user_name) )
    {
         $record = array('username'=> $username,
             'friend' => $friendname);

         $this->db->insert('friends', $record);
    }
}

function getFollowing($username)
{
    $following = array();
    $this->db->select('*')->from('friends')->where('username', $username);
    $followingSet = $this->db->get();

    if( !empty($followingSet) )
    {
         foreach ($followingSet->result() as $row)
         {
              $following[] = $row->friend;
         }
    }
    return $following;
 }
```

Also i would like you to suggest, always check that an array is not empty before using it. Like you used it in **foreach** loop, the loop will generate an error.

Comment: Now this did work as far as not being able to add any more friends at all once Ive added one person to follow - I now cannot add any more followers no matter whether Im already following them or not

Answer (score 0):

Try This where you want to apply query for reading something, Apply distinct in db query

```
   $this->db->distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model try something like this:

```
/**
 * Return true if don't find row in DB.
 * @param array $ay_value
 * @param array $ay_column
 * @param string $table
 * @throws Exception
 * @return boolean
 */

public function check_double_content($ay_value, $ay_column, $table) {

    if ((is_array($ay_value)) AND (is_array($ay_column))) {

        if (count($ay_value) == count($ay_column)) {

            foreach ($ay_column AS $key => $column) {
                $this->db->where($column, $ay_value[$key]);
            }

            $this->db->from($table);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }



        } else {
            throw new Exception("\$ay_value and \$ay_coulm must have same rows");
        }

    } else {
        throw new Exception("\$ay_value and \$ay_column must by array");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code dumps as answers without a clear explanation of how they answer the question.