# Is there something like $this->db->matched_rows() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update an entry in table or insert if not exist. I am using `affected_rows()` function but in case if data is unchanged it returns 0 and inserts a duplicate row.

I am using this code,

```
$datainsert = array(
    "vendor_id"   => $vendor_id,
    "c_date_time" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
$this->api_vendor_model->update_vendor_login_time($vendor_id, $datainsert);
if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 0) {
    $this->api_vendor_model->insert_vendor_login_time($datainsert);
}
```

but it does not work in case no rows are affected but an entry exists for vendor_id.

```
function update_vendor_login_time($vendor_id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
    $this->db->update('fa_vendor_login_time', $data);
    $this->error_check(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

Comment: Paste code of `update_vendor_login_time()` model function!!

Comment: question edited with update function code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of controller you need to check `$this->db->affected_rows()`  in model file  and `return TRUE or FALSE`. To check duplicate entry your need to check it using select query

**MODEL**

```
 function update_vendor_login_time($vendor_id, $data) {
    $q = $this->db->select('id')// add your column nae here
                    ->from('fa_vendor_login_time')
                    ->where(array('vendor_id' => $vendor_id))->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() == 0) {
        $this->db->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
        $this->db->update('fa_vendor_login_time', $data);
        $this->error_check(__FUNCTION__);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLER**

```
$insert = $this->api_vendor_model->update_vendor_login_time($vendor_id, $datainsert);
if (!$insert) {

    $this->api_vendor_model->insert_vendor_login_time($datainsert);
}
```

Comment: what difference would it make? it would still return false if datainsert values already present and thus will insert a duplicate entry

Comment: check this to prevent duplicate entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970942/how-to-prevent-duplicate-records-in-codeigniter

Comment: so that does mean i will have to fire a get query before update or insert

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such function.

`affected_rows()` works that way because that's how the database works - it won't return feedback for rows it didn't actually update. This is outside of the framework's control.

Comment: is there any way other than firing a get query before update or insert?